# Facebook API read conversation of managed page?

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I am trying to read inbox of pages

```
$facebook->api( '/page_id/conversations');
```

I have the below permissions

```
"user_photos,manage_pages,user_likes,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_stream,read_friendlists,read_page_mailboxes"
```

Other requests are working such as :

```
 $facebook->api( '/page_id/conversations');
```

Doesn't work, Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You said other requests are working such as "$facebook->api( '/page_id/conversations');". That seems like the same as the one that doesn't work. Could you please clarify which requests work? Also, do you have the page token access?